# add incremnting seconds to time in HH:mm:ssPM format

Tags: matlab, date, plot, date-arithmetic

How to add a vector of seconds to time HH:mm:ssPM in MATAB?

I usually have this nice way in Excel to convert normal number format to hour and minutes and sec. format using simple cell custom formatting, but when I put down code below in MATLAB, instead of incrementing in seconds, it adds in days!

```
time = 1+0:50000+0;     % sec

% To show date as plot label it should be converted from numbers to letters 
hr_matlab = time' + datenum('4:10:44 PM');
hr= datestr(hr_matlab, 'HH:MM:ssPM');

figure(222)
plot(hr,S,'-b','LineWidth',2)
```

I am using MATLAB2014a and don't have access to function `datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datenum` converts the date to a number that represents **days** as whole numbers. For that reason, when you add the vector [1,2,3,...], you acturally add days to your fixed time `('4:10:44 PM')`.

if you want to add it as seconds, you need to divide `time` in the amount of seconds per day:

```
hr_matlab = (time')/86400 + datenum('4:10:44 PM');
```

Comment: complex conjugate transpose `'`  is not needed here

Comment: I just wanted to keep the OP's format, so he can see exactly where the fix in the code. It really doesn't matter when you have a vector of natural numbers. But maybe the right way should be `time.'`, thank for the attention.

Comment: It really *does* matter.  Getting used to bad practices *does* matter.

Answer (score 1):

One simple option is to add two [date numbers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html):

```
hr_matlab = datenum('4:10:44 PM') + datenum(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.');
```